# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject | Не валидная строка?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь вписать данные из строки в объект.
Не получается, пишет что строка не валидная, но это не так.

Строка(форматировал для удобства):

```
[
{
"timestamp": "2020-02-24T22:34:05.080Z",
"name": "SomeName",
"side": "red",
"number": 4,
"number2": 123.5,
"tickDirection": "MinusTick",
"trdMatchID": "f221055f-fef1-24cb-b21c-5dc717e6bc87",
"grossValue": 20686,
"homeNotional": 0.00020686,
"foreignNotional": 2
}
]
```

Вот так я пытаюсь распарсить её в объект:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Myobjs.obj>(stroka);`

Ошибка :

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type
'Myobjs.obj' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
to deserialize correctly.
```

Myobj:

```
public class LastTrade
    {
        public DateTime timestamp { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string side { get; set; }
        public int number { get; set; }
        public int number2 { get; set; }
        public string tickDirection { get; set; }
        public string trdMatchID { get; set; }
        public int grossValue { get; set; }
        public int homeNotional { get; set; }
        public int foreignNotional { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Вы делаете не так то, что не показываете в вопросе что такое `Myobjs.obj`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<LastTrade>>(stroka);
```

---

По-моему, это не `int`-ы:

```
"number2": 123.5,
...
"homeNotional": 0.00020686,
```